# MS Interop Word, Excel multiple opened files DocumentBeforeClose handling

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, office-interop

I have a module like windows explorer in my app. 
I want to handle opening and closing the word and excel files in that module.
When I'm opening f.e. 4-5 files at the same time, the close handler doesn't work correctly.

**The problem is:** sometimes after closing the Word app, my app is not stopping on breakpoint at the beginning of wordDocEvents_DocumentBeforeClose function.
Seems something related inter process communication, because every opened document is a new process.

If it is known issue please help, otherwise I'll try to do something in my codes.

code snapshot:

```
if (_wordApp == null)
{
    _wordApp = new Word.Application();
    _wordDocEvents = (Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)_wordApp;
    if (!isLocked)
    {
        //_wordDocEvents.Quit += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_QuitEventHandler(wordDocEvents_Quit);
        _wordDocEvents.DocumentBeforeClose += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeCloseEventHandler(wordDocEvents_DocumentBeforeClose);
        _wordDocEvents.DocumentBeforeSave += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler(wordDocEvents_DocumentBeforeSave);
        _wordApp.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
    }
}
_wordApp.Visible = true;
Word.Document oDoc = _wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName, null, isLocked);

oDoc.Activate();
_wordApp.Visible = true;
_wordApp.Activate();
```

close handler:

```
void wordDocEvents_DocumentBeforeClose(Word.Document doc, ref bool Cancel)
{
    if (!doc.Saved)
    {
        MessageBoxResult res = MessageBox.Show(ApplicationValues.GetResourceString("library_file_save_changes"), "", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question, MessageBoxResult.Yes, System.Windows.MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
        switch (res)
        {
            case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
            doc.Save();
                break;
            case MessageBoxResult.No:
                doc.Saved = true;
                break;
            default:
                Cancel = true;
                return;
        }
    }
    interopFileBeforeCloseHandler(doc.FullName, doc.ReadOnly);

}
```

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? We're having the same problem.

Comment: Still no answer to this question...?:( Im also having the same problem.. Sometimes close event triggers, sometimes it doesnt...

Comment: I just stop using MS Interop that was my solution sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an older one, but I figured it out after finding this thread at msdn:
[workbookbeforeclose-event-does-not-fire](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d778219-a92f-4a38-8ea7-fd1bc6bc7fb8/workbookbeforeclose-event-does-not-fire?forum=vsto)

So a rather easy solution is to store all created/loaded Documents to an array/list/... so the garbage collector doesn't dispose them, when it thinks it needs to do so, thus clearing all the event handlers.

Worked like a charm for me ;)